# How to get a scholarship for PhD?

Tags: phd, funding, united-states, canada

I have a master degree in Management with extensive work experience. Now, I wish to continue my education, but cannot afford it without a proper scholarship. As I see, many people have good scholarships for PhD programs, but I tried to get one in the UK universities, but there was only a few.

This year, I want to try Canadian and American universities, but I feel I am missing something. There should be more practical approach (than limiting to scholarships advertised on university websites).

I appreciate any advice that how can I find a decent scholarship in North American universities. I do not expect top university or highly paid scholarships.

Answer (score 1):

If you could find a department that is fairly close to your interests that has a lot of teaching assistants (TAs), that would be a great way to fund your studies.  I suspect Management is not such a department.  I wonder if Economics would have enough affinity?  Perhaps Economics would have a pretty good number of TA positions.

Another possibility might be to try to find a job that would pay for your schooling.  This might require a part-time school schedule, at least initially.